# Lock and insert a row in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert a row and return the identity column value from a procedure! For this I dont want to use any advanced things like `@@identity` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY` etc as I don't have a clear picture about how they work.
So I am planning to do this

1. lock a table
2. do the insert
3. return the max of table

I am familiar with oracle lock

```
lock table tab1 in exclusive mode;
INSERT INTO tab1.....;
select max(id) into retVal from tab1;
```

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with my approach?
2. How can i achieve this in SQL SERVER?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your approach, yes.  You are rejecting the best way to do something instead of learning how it works.

Comment: Explicitly locking a table is a seriously bad idea, even in Oracle.  You should only consider it in SQL Server if you are an expert.  And the vast majority of SQL Server experts would never do it.

Comment: Just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, that's what it was made for.

Comment: @DanBracuk actually there is a [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) which says there are some bugs around these. So i am not very comfortable with them & I am having oracle background!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which version of sql server it is?

If you are running sql server 2008+ (r2 i thing)

The safest way is to use the output statement of an insert.

Like this :

insert into Customer (Name,  Address, Phone)
    output inserted.CustomerId into @CustomerId
values (......)

Answer (score 1):

You'll be creating more problems than solving by forcing locks on your database/tables.  Let the Database Management System (DBMS) manage the database.

All you need to do is:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION --added after original answer
    INSERT INTO tab1....;
    SELECT @@identity AS [last_id] INTO retVal;
END TRANSACTION --added after original answer
```

I trust you know that you can only `SELECT...INTO retVal` so long as the `retVal` table doesn't already exist.

Comment: @coge-soft Thanks for the reply. My worry is that i read @@identity `returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session` so if at the same time there is some other insert by some other user in some other table then will it take that value? As I already said i dont know the adv topics how the SQLserver handles sessions or scopes and all!!

Comment: You should be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` here, not `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: Thanks @RBarryYoung i read something about that here [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/) I am not aware of parallel plans and all. DO you if this bug still exists?

Comment: @Rams, I edited my code that (should) alleviate those concerns.  Adding `BEGIN` and `END` as I did put the entire code into one transaction.

Comment: @Rams Should be fixed by now.  If you're concerned, then just use `OPTION(MAXDP 1)`.

Comment: `BEGIN`...`END` blocks have *nothing* to do with transactions.